# 'CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT' but all the syntax seems to be ok

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have an issue with a cUrl. Recently, I have found that the problem is in the syntax of the curl, because when I dump the request I want to execute and put it in PostMan it works, but the function inside my code doesn't and returns 3: 'CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT'. For information my curl version is 7.79.1

I have tried some different approaches with CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, CURLOPT_POST and etc, but it does not work...

Here is my function:

```
private function cUrl_CreateContactFastFood($merchant_token, $arr)
            {
                $status = "active";                         
                $Contact_name = $arr["customerName"];               
                $Contact_email = '';
                                
                if($Contact_email=='') {
                        $Contact_email= 'FastFoodCustomer@ttt.com'; 
                }
                        
                $Contact_phone = $arr["phoneNumber"];   
                $Contact_address = $arr["endAddressResolved"];                  

                $url = 'http://dostavka-bg.com/api_services/insert_contact';
                $curl_params = '?keys=f74192da825962d3b1c2b2aa616ab68b&merchant_token='.$merchant_token.'&name='.$Contact_name.'&email='.$Contact_email.'&phone='.$Contact_phone.'&address='.$Contact_address.'&status='.$status;
                                   
                $ch = curl_init();
                $headers = array(
                  'Accept: */*',
                  'User-Agent: ',
                  'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
                  'Host: dostavka-bg.com',
                  'Connection: keep-alive'
                );
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.$curl_params);
            
                $data = curl_exec($ch);
                if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
                }

                curl_close($ch);

            }
```

Here is the solved problem:

```
private function cUrl_CreateContactFastFood($merchant_token, $arr)
            {
                $status = "active";
                            
                $Contact_name = $arr["customerName"];

                                
                $Contact_email = '';//$arr["customer"]["invoicing_details"]["company_address"];
                if($Contact_email==''){
                     $Contact_email= 'FastFoodCustomer@ttt.com';                                
                }
                        
                $Contact_phone = $arr["phoneNumber"];   
                $Contact_address = $arr["endAddressResolved"];                  
            
                $url = 'http://dostavka-bg.com/api_services/insert_contact';
                
                $curl_params = '?keys=f74192da825962d3b1c2b2aa616ab68b&merchant_token='.urlencode($merchant_token).'&name='.urlencode($Contact_name).
                '&email='.urlencode($Contact_email).'&phone='.urlencode($Contact_phone).'&address='.urlencode($Contact_address).'&status='.urlencode($status);
                
                $ch = curl_init();
                
                $headers = array(
                  'Accept: */*',
                  'User-Agent: ',
                  'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
                  'Host: dostavka-bg.com',
                  'Connection: keep-alive'
                );
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.$curl_params);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                
                $data = curl_exec($ch); 

                if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
                }
                
                $info = curl_version();
             
                curl_close($ch);
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: Your URL probably contains some rubbish characters like perhaps a linefeed or a space?

Comment: I do not see any spaces. But I have seen something interesting. In postman it works, but when I get rid of Host header (<calculated when request is sent>) it stops. Is there any way to add host in mu curl above?

Comment: You are using insecure `http://` URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you're passing includes several query string parameters, only some of which are shown in your example, but some of which probably include punctuation or other characters which aren't allowed in URLs. Those need to be correctly encoded by either:

- Calling [urlencode](https://www.php.net/urlencode) or [rawurlencode](https://www.php.net/rawurlencode) on each parameter as you build up the query string.
- Using [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/http_build_query) to format it all for you, rather than manually concatenating the parts.

Comment: I really appreciate you help. urlencode solve my problem. Have a nice and successful week. friend !